# The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.Please help me

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my url:

http://localhost/BlueSky.Com/home/post_page/id=1&category=Web%20Designing
and

this is the error:

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: Find `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in your `/application/config/config.php` file. You might need to update it.

Comment: I use this. but not working. $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@\=';

Comment: in form you posting chas which is not in this $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@\='– ;  if its - then add that before single quote not after that

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\=+';

Comment: it's work for you. let me know.

Comment: Edit your question with the code where your url is created you may want to use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php as well

Comment: thanks. but not working-Sanjay Kumar

Answer (score 0):

you must edit your `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in file `config.php` like this.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@\=-@\()&,+';
```